# Why Double.parseDouble(String) can be computed easily up to 1E22?

Tags: java, parsing, double

Today I dived into the implementation of OpenJDK `Double.parseDouble(String)`.

The first part consist of validating input, finding the sign, the relevant digits (mantissa) and eventually the exponent (with its sign).
After that, here comes the time to create the double value that will be returned and I stopped on the following piece of code :

```
// possibly an easy case.
// We know that the digits can be represented
// exactly. And if the exponent isn't too outrageous,
// the whole thing can be done with one operation,
// thus one rounding error.
// isNegative indicates if the number being parsed is negative
// dValue is the mantissa
// exp is the exponent
if (exp >= 0) {
    if (exp <= MAX_SMALL_TEN) {
        //
        // Can get the answer with one operation,
        // thus one roundoff.
        //
        double rValue = dValue * SMALL_10_POW[exp];
        return (isNegative) ? -rValue : rValue;
    }
    int slop = MAX_DECIMAL_DIGITS - kDigits;
    if (exp <= MAX_SMALL_TEN + slop) {
        //
        // We can multiply dValue by 10^(slop)
        // and it is still "small" and exact.
        // Then we can multiply by 10^(exp-slop)
        // with one rounding.
        //
        dValue *= SMALL_10_POW[slop];
        double rValue = dValue * SMALL_10_POW[exp - slop];
        return (isNegative) ? -rValue : rValue;
    }
    //
    // Else we have a hard case with a positive exp.
    //
} else {
   //Deal with negative exp (omitted here)
}
```

Here are the definitions of constants :

```
static final int    MAX_DECIMAL_DIGITS = 15;
private static final double[] SMALL_10_POW = {
            1.0e0,
            1.0e1, 1.0e2, 1.0e3, 1.0e4, 1.0e5,
            1.0e6, 1.0e7, 1.0e8, 1.0e9, 1.0e10,
            1.0e11, 1.0e12, 1.0e13, 1.0e14, 1.0e15,
            1.0e16, 1.0e17, 1.0e18, 1.0e19, 1.0e20,
            1.0e21, 1.0e22
        };
private static final int MAX_SMALL_TEN = SMALL_10_POW.length-1;
```

As we can see in the code,in the "easy case" we can compute the value with a simple statement : `double rValue = dValue * SMALL_10_POW[exp]` if `exponent <= MAX_SMALL_TEN //=22`. If and only if exponent is greater than 22, `Double.parseDouble(String)` go to a "hard case" branch where it makes an initial guess and plays with BigInteger afterwards ...

**What introduced this limitation at 1.0E22 ?**
Follow-up question : 
**Why is the hack with the slop variable acceptable if there is a limitation at 1.0E22?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What introduced this limitation at 1.0E22?

The fact that 10<sup>22</sup> is the largest power of 10 which has an exact representation as a `double`.

A `double` (on x86) holds 53 bits of precision. 10<sup>22</sup> is considerably more than 2<sup>53</sup> -- it's just over 2<sup>73</sup> -- but its last 22 bits are 0, so only 52 bits of mantissa are required to represent it exactly. 10<sup>23</sup> would require 54 bits, which is more than are available. (10<sup>*N*</sup> is 5<sup>*N*</sup> * 2<sup>*N*</sup>, so the last *N* bits are 0. Since 5<sup>*N*</sup> is odd, the bit just before the *N* trailing 0s is  1.)

The fast path multiplication produces the correctly rounded result if the two values multiplied are exact. (That's required by the floating point standard.)

But that's not the only case where we can guarantee correctness. If one number (the decimal digits) is not too large, the total error when multiplying by a slightly inexact exponent will not be large enough to alter the rounded result.

The "slop" criterion is an attempt to conservatively estimate how large "not too large" can be. (I don't know how good the criterion is. But that's its intent.)

Comment: Thanks that’s exactly the explanation I need.